# Bootstrap nav tabs...where to put 100% on ul and 20% to each tab to fill the entire space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap nav tabs...where to put 100% on ul and 20% to each tab to fill the entire space?

I'd like my five bootstrap nav tabs to be spread out evenly across the containers. Currently they are in the middle, but there is so much blank space on the left and right sides of the tabs.

I think if I put my UL to be 100% and have each tab at 20% it may work. But where do I put those values?

**Also, when I click "Grape Trees", it just shows the same information as "Bananas". Why won't it change?**

here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/GB3f0moehB

Here's my HTML:

```
   <div class="content-section-c">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2>Sample Search Results</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">APPLE<br>
                TREES
                               </a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">ORANGE<br>TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">PEARS <br> TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">BANANAS<br>&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">GRAPE<br> TREES</a></li> 
                           </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
              <p class="results">126 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
                                                  </div>
            <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
            <p class="results">75 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/05_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/06_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/07_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/08_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
              <p class="results">144 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/09_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/10_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/11_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/12_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
              <p class="results">170 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane5" class="tab-pane">
              <p class="results">256 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
        </div><!-- /.tabbable -->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-section-c -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
        .content-section-c {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3C5A78;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #d4d4d4 !important; 
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover{
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

.nav-tabs{
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block; /* needed to center the list items */
}

.tabbable{
     text-align: center;
}

.results {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #355A78;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%` to `.nav-tabs` and create a new style for li as below

```
  .nav-tabs li {
    width: 20%;
  }
```

**http://www.bootply.com/93t8KTXgnA**

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent ul ".nav-tabs" 100% so it should fill the width of the container. Then make each li element under the ".nav-tabs" 20%:

```
.nav-tabs{
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block; /* needed to center the list items */
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-tabs>li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-tabs {width: 100%} .nav-tabs > li {width: 20%;}
```

+

You should change attr href of Grapes

```
 `<li><a href="#pane5" data-toggle="tab">GRAPE<br> TREES</a></li> `
```